# How can I prompt an abbreviate date with SpreadsheetApp.promp() in Google Sheets Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, date-formatting

I have a prompt that also displays some values to the user, one of them being a date. The problem is: this displays a too detailed date (ex.: `Tue Mar 30 2021 06:29:23 GMT-0400` (Hora de verão oriental norte-americana)). How can I abbreviate this date only for the prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 2 methods, `toLocaleDateString()` or `toDateString()` to shorten your date in Apps Script, as seen below:

```
function myFunction() {
   var d = new Date();
    var date = d.toLocaleDateString();
    var date2 = d.toDateString();

    Logger.log(date);
    Logger.log(date2);
}
```

These 2 methods will give you a shorten date format as seen here:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach would be to use the [Utilities.formatDate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)) function:

```
function displayPrompt() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),"EE MMM dd y");
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const response = ui.prompt('Title', formattedDate, ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
}
```

This would give you this prompt window:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you need complete control of the output, use [`Utilities.formatDate`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)), which returns a string:

```js
var d = new Date();
var tz = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(d, tz, "yyyy-MM-dd");
Logger.log(formattedDate);
```

[`SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet?hl=en#getspreadsheettimezone) gives you the time zone for the parent spreadsheet, but you can alternatively hardcode a value from [this list](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html) (e.g., `"GMT"`).